# What is this weird plane?

Tags: aircraft-identification

Can anyone identify the make and model of this aircraft? I'm just really curious.

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From what I can tell, it's a Burt Rutan design. I then searched and it appears to be a [Rutan Defiant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rutan_Defiant).

Comment: I was initiall guessing a [Starship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Starship), but I think you're right.

Comment: No, Starship is twin pusher, but it's also a Rutan Design.

Comment: @keshlam and the starship has smaller canards

Comment: @keshlam and is quite a bit larger

Comment: Good points, all.